# JS - set window height using current window size

Tags: javascript, css, height, document-body

I have some CSS that needs the body to have a height set, but this needs to be done depending on the user.

I have made some code that kind of works - it calculates the window height but it's not changing the body height. What am I doing wrong?

```
function setWindowHeight(){
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body').style.height = windowHeight + "px";
}
```

Comment: Which browser do you use? In example the IE has a different syntax rather Firefox and co.

Comment: I'm using an iPad, so webkit.

Comment: I think something is missing on your code -document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.height = windowHeight + "px";

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add an eventListener, and you don't need to use the getElementsByTagName because has only 1 body tag:

```
function setWindowHeight(){
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    document.body.style.height = windowHeight + "px";
    console.log(document.body.style.height);
}
window.addEventListener("resize",setWindowHeight,false);
```

Or, if you want to use, you can do this:

```
function setWindowHeight(){
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.height = windowHeight + "px";
    console.log(document.body.style.height);
//---------------------------------------´
//will get the first element tagged body
}
window.addEventListener("resize",setWindowHeight,false);
```

**EDIT (Changed the code above):** you can check the value in the Firefox Console. Open it(CTRL + SHIFT + K) and resize the window, you will see the event *resize* be fired when you do it.

Comment: Thank you Erick! Much appreciated. I'm trying to learn JS but this was a bit beyond me.

Answer (score -1):

```
try this may work 

document.getElementsByTagName('body').height  = windowHeight + "px";
```